# Message Sent To Deallocated Instance ... As far as I can tell, there's no reason it should be deallocated

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nstimer, dealloc

I am working on an Iphone App that uses a SQLite database as its main source of Model data.

When the app opens, the singleton object called "Model" scans the SQLite table, uses each row to create a "Result" object (an NSObject subclass), and then adds each Result to an NSMutableArray.

Here's the code for that section, starting right after I have found the path for the database:

```
- (void)populateResultArrayWith:(NSString *)dbPath {

const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM results";
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSInteger pkInt = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
        NSNumber *pk = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pkInt];
        NSString *v = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
        NSString *n = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
        NSNumber *c = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 4)];
        NSString *t1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];
        NSString *t2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
        NSString *t3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 7)];

        Result *resultObj = [[Result alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:(NSNumber *)pk
                                                      withVerb:(NSString *)v
                                                      withNoun:(NSString *)n
                                                    withSuffix:(NSString *)s
                                                      withCost:(NSNumber *)c
                                                      withTag1:(NSString *)t1
                                                      withTag2:(NSString *)t2
                                                       andTag3:(NSString *)t3];

        [self.resultArray addObject:resultObj];
        [resultObj release];
    }
}
else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
    NSLog(@"Model: Closing Database");
}
```

Later, one of my view controllers tells my Model to start a repeating NSTimer, and triggers a method to generate a random result from the NSMutableArray:

```
-(void)startTimer
{
if (startDate && startDate != nil) {
    startDate = nil;
}
self.modelCumulativeValueWasted = 0;
startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
modelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) 
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(tick) 
                                       userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
[self randomResult];
}
```

And:

```
-(Result *)randomResult
{
if (randomResult != nil) {
    randomResult=nil;
}

NSLog(@"Selected Result Retain Count At Beginning of Method = %i", [randomResult retainCount]);
// Generate a random int between 0 and the total count of the resultArray.
int randomIndex = arc4random() % [resultArray count];

// Select a result from the resultArray at that index - with an iVar.
randomResult = [resultArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
NSLog(@"Selected Result Retain Count At End of Method= %i", [randomResult retainCount]);

return randomResult;
}
```

The console read-out tells me that the retain count is normal during the course of this method... randomResult starts with a retain count of 0 after the opening if/then statement, and a retain count of 1 after it has been returned.

Then my Model applies some calculations based on other model data to generate a formatted Result string for display in the view:

```
-(void)calculateQuantity
{
    // Get the float of the randomly selected result's "cost" property.
    selectedCostFloat = [randomResult.cost floatValue];

    // Calculate "how many of this result item could we buy" by dividing the cumulativeValueWasted by the costFloat.
    float quantityFloat = (modelCumulativeValueWasted / selectedCostFloat);
    NSLog(@"Quantity Float = %f", quantityFloat);
    // Save this float as an NSNumber object, so a NSNumberFormatter can interpret it in ResultVC.
    quantityNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:quantityFloat];
}
```

My problem is that every time this method is called, and my model tries to get the floatValue of the NSNumber *cost property, I get a crash (using breakpoints, I isolated the first line of *calculateQuantity:* as the crash-point), and I get the following message in the console:

**-[CFNumber floatValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6332280**

The way this works is that *[sharedModel calculateQuantity];* is being called on the first tick of the timer, and then it crashes:

```
-(void)tick
{
// For "Time" every tick
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval countInSeconds = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

NSDate *modelTimerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:countInSeconds];
self.modelTimeString = [df stringFromDate:modelTimerDate];
NSLog(@"Time String: %@",self.modelTimeString);

//For "$" every tick
self.modelCumulativeValueWasted += self.modelMeetingValuePerSecond;

self.modelNumberToDisplayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%1.2f",self.modelCumulativeValueWasted];
NSLog(@"Cumulative Money Wasted: %@",self.modelNumberToDisplayString);

[self calculateQuantity];
}
```

I don't believe I am calling anything twice, and my memory management looks fine.

The most confusing part is that if I move the first couple lines of the *calculateQuantity* method to the end of the *randomResult* method, I still get the crash. Even after the console JUST told me that the retain count was 1, it immediately says I am trying to send a message to a deallocated instance.

I know this looks like a question that comes up a lot, but I haven't been able to figure out the problem from any of the other threads.

Comment: How is the `Result`'s `initWith**` method written?

Answer (score 0):

First, never rely on the `-retainCount` since the system may do some magics on it.

Second, the `randomResult` is return from `resultArray`, so the `randomResult`'s owner is `resultArray`, you don't know when the owner release its member. To own a object by yourself, you should send it a `-retain` message, so change it to

```
-(Result *)randomResult
{
  ...
  randomResult = [resultArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];    
  return [[randomResult retain] autorelease];
}
```

Should be OK. Give it a try.

Comment: That was a great idea -- I believe it was the solution. I also looked back at my Result Init method. Turns out, I made a big memory management oversight, and init the properties like this --> verb = aVerb, noun = aNoun, etc. when I should have used --> self.verb = aVerb, self.noun = aNoun. I believe that made the big difference!

Comment: Oh... and the other other big problem was my custom getter method for -(Result *)randomResult was getting called by objects just trying to reference its properties, e.g. sharedModel.randomResult.cost. When that got called, my getter method went into effect and a new random result was generated, which was messing everything up. I changed that method to -(void)generateRandomResult instead to clear it up